# Aligning chart image to right and legend to left

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts

I have a pie chart in my word (data comes from excel). I can not align the pie itself to the right side of the text because the margin box does not allow me:

[image]

I can just push it a little bit to right until it is impossible! the only way is to resize the pie chart and make it so small...but that will kill the point.

[image]

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried cropping the box?

Comment: It seems hard to to set the position of the image in the Plot Area individually.

Comment: I would suggest saving a document with the problem on OneDrive or DropBox and posting a link here. A picture of a car engine does not let a mechanic check the spark plugs. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258